# Why does this derivation not work for showing $M_{12}= M_{21}$ for mutual inductance?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, inductance

If we assume two inductors behave like the centers of ideal solenoids then the induced emf in inductor 2 due to inductor 1 will be found by $-N_2 \frac{d \phi_{21}}{dt}$. But the induced emf is also equal to $-M_{21} \frac{dI_1}{dt}$.  Equating these two equations and substituting $\phi_{21} = A_2 L_1 I_1 / (N_1 A_1)$, we get:
\begin{align}
N_2 \frac{A_2}{A_1} \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{L_1 I_1}{N_1} \right ) = M_{21} \frac{dI}{dt}.
\end{align}
However, after finding the same formula for $M_{12}$, I noticed that according to these formulas $M_{21}$ and $M_{12}$ are not equal to each other.

I think there should be a term added to the current inside of the derivative in order to subtract the opposite current induced in inductor 1 because of the magnetic flux through inductor 1 that is due to the magnetic flux from inductor 2. In calculating the current induced by a regular bar magnet, for example, such a term would not be needed. I do not know how to approach calculating this current however, I keep getting second order derivatives and still cannot prove M12= M21.

Here is an image describing the situation above. The field lines however, would not fringe in the idealized setup described above. The two coils can be connected by an iron core. This set-up might be unrealistic, but this won't change the fact that the mathematics should lead to the same result.
[image]

source for image: Hyperphysics

Comment: Why do you think $\phi_{21}$ has that value? How did you arrive at conclusion $M$'s are not equal? Describe your work.

Comment: @JánLalinský , the flux through inductor 2 due to inductor 1 will be equal to the magnetic flux linkage through the first inductor (ignoring the different areas the coils of the inductors might have). However, when substituting the inductance of an ideal solenoid, there is a length factor. So in both equations the length of the inductors will be a different variable and the two equations won't be equal unless the lengths of the inductors are equal.

Comment: That makes no sense. Why would flux through inductor 2 due to inductor 1 (which depends on current $I_1$ and geometry of both circuits) be equal to magnetic flux linkage through the first inductor?

Comment: @JánLalinský , assuming the coils of the second inductor have the same area as the first inductor, or even a different area, I don't see why the formula I wrote above wouldn't work. I did include the area relation in the post. Do you mean something else by geometry?  By the induced EMF equation, the induced EMF should be directly proportional to the change in magnetic flux, which can be directly found from the magnetic flux created in inductor 1 in an idealized setup.

Comment: You should add a picture where the geometry of inductors is shown. Is one inductor inside the other one? If so, then the formula could work for one of them, but not the other one. Also, it is better to use the symbol $\phi$ for the whole magnetic flux through the inductor, not just flux per one turn.

Comment: @JánLalinský , I included the picture in the post.

Comment: It is not realistic to assume that magnetic field lines do not diverge. Magnetic induction outside the coil is much lower than inside the coil, and strongly depends on distance. The formula you've suggested would be valid if both inductors occupied the same space.

Comment: @JánLalinský , is there a formula to calculate the magnetic induction outside of the coil?

Comment: @JánLalinský , also, I still don't see why this doesn't work. Yes, this doesn't occur in reality, but if it did the formula would have to produce the same result. The basic equations describing mutual inductance don't require any information about the divergence of the field, the distance separating the two coils or how the flux in one coil changes as it leaves that coil and enters the other (other than the permeability constant).

Comment: It doesn't work because magnetic field of inductor 1 is not uniform in the region where the inductor 2 is. Magnetic field is approximately uniform inside the solenoid, but not outside. The general equation for mutual inductance takes into account diverging field lines. See section III in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224394021_Implementation_of_the_Neumann_formula_for_calculating_the_mutual_inductance_between_planar_PCB_inductors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138352/discussion-between-piksiki-and-jan-lalinsky).